# Spring 4 - Authentication with preAuthorize & PostAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-4

NOTE: My application uses the latest version of the Spring framework, 4.0.6, 3.2.4 for security, and, it uses no xml but only Java-Config to configure the application.

I have a set of services which I would like to secure with roles and other business specific authorization conditions. This services are grouped into a module (a jar) which is used by a REST application and a web application. I already have an `AuthenticationProvider` in the web application (REST application is in initial phase). I use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`in the web application. Having said that, I now need to secure the methods in the services too. In that case, do I need to provide another authentication provider? Or, is right to move the authentication provider to the services module so that the web/rest apps uses the authentication provider in the services jar? If I configure `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` in the ApplicationServiceConfig.java of the services module, I get the blow exception.

```
com.name.mvoice.project.service.ApplicationServiceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
```

How do I configure the security if the application requires double authentication, one from the RDBMS and the other from the LDAP. The condition should be that the user information should be present and be enabled in both the systems. Do I need to write this in the existing authentication manager itself or shall I provide separate auth provider for the LDAP? If so how?

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
 @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    AuthenticationProvider dbAuthenticationProvider = new DatabaseAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.authenticationProvider(dbAuthenticationProvider );
    // is it right to do like this
   AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LDAPAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider );
 }
```

Though, I see`AuthenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider` adds the supplied authenticationprovider to a list!

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't give you the desired result.  The default Spring Security implementation uses only one `AuthenticationProvider` at a time.  Your second call to `auth.authenticationProvider()` would force Spring Security to use just the LDAP provider.

To achieve what you want

**Step 1**: Create a class of your own, say

```
public class CompositeAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {}
```

**Step 2**: Then, inject the Database and LDAP providers into it.

**Step 3**: In the `authenticate` method of the class `CompositeAuthenticationProvider`, orchestrate the request between the Database and LDAP providers as you see fit.  Return a response based on the results you obtain from both the providers.

Comment: Okay, got it. But why does the AuthenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider add the supplied provider to a list? I read somewhere in the spring doc that any one among the supplied auth providers should return a right value then spring will take it. I didnt dig too much into the spring code.

Comment: I too haven't dug too deep into the documentation but I have outlined the approach that I have used on my own projects after a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that. Any thought about my first question?